# Getting a dependency injection error when I try to add route parameters to my Angular component

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I want to make a component that uses a route parameter. Resources online all suggest that this is pretty easy with the ActivatedRoute syntax. But whenever I try, I keep getting this error:

> Error: NG0202: This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection because its dependency at index 0 of the parameter list is invalid.
> This can happen if the dependency type is a primitive like a string or if an ancestor of this class is missing an Angular decorator.
>
> Please check that 1) the type for the parameter at index 0 is correct and 2) the correct Angular decorators are defined for this class and its ancestors.

Edit for minimal-but-thorough code sample:

`products.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ProductsRoutingModule } from './products_routing.module';
import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';
import { ProductDetailsComponent } from './product_details/product_details.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ProductsRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ProductsComponent,
    ProductDetailsComponent
  ]
})
export class ProductsModule { }
```

`products_routing.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';
import { ProductDetailsComponent } from './product_details/product_details.component';

const productRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProductsComponent,
    children: [ {
      path: 'details',
      component: ProductDetailsComponent
    } ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(productRoutes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class ProductsRoutingModule { }
```

`products.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import template from './products.component.html';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  template
})
export class ProductsComponent { }
```

`products.component.html`

```
<h2>Products generally</h2>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

`product_details.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import template from './product_details.component.html';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-details',
  template
})
export class ProductDetailsComponent {
  constructor (
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }
}
```

`product_details.component.html`

```
<h3>Product details component</h3>
```

What's missing? I tried importing `RouterModule` in the Products module file, but that didn't seem to help.

Could esbuild be messing this up?

Comment: What is the whole content for the `@Component` decorator? I see an incomplete `template` in there, nevermind, you are importing it... interesting. What exactly does the `template` have from the other component?

Comment: The `template` is imported from an HTML file. Nothing special is going on in that file. The component displays properly if I don't try to use `ActivatedRoute`.

Comment: could you try deleting the template import and just set the usual value as `productDetail.component.html` and see if the dependency injection complains? Make sure to have that template HTML though

Comment: I just put in a minimal version of the whole module, hope that helps

Comment: Is this a problem with my bundler? I'm using esbuild